# SQL How to select two Distinct tow coll one not

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i have a table such as:

```
C1 |C2 |C3 |C4

int|int|int|datetime (day and HH:MM:SS)
```

and i need to write a query that for each C1 and C2 returns the most recent C3 (in terms of C4), it should be order by C1(asc), C2(asc).

```
ex:
C1|C2|C3|C4

4 |4 |4 |02.02.2016 10:20:00

4 |4 |6 |02.02.2016 10:21:00

3 |1 |5 |02.02.2016 10:18:00

2 |8 |73 |02.02.2016 11:23:00

5 |3 |-2 |02.02.2016 09:23:00

returns:
C1|C2|C3  =>C1 and C2 asc order!

2 |8 |73

3 |1 |5

4 |4 |6 

5 |3 |-2
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using? MySQL and MS SQL Server are two very different databases.

Comment: Give it a try at least.

Comment: both, i need an answer, an ideea

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server you can use a CTE. This CTE assigns row numbers based on c1 / c2 pairing with the most recent c4 (date) being 1.

```
with n as(
    select
        c1,
        c2,
        c3,
        ROW_NUMBER over (partition by c1, c2, order by c4 desc) as rn
    from someTable)

select c1, c2, c3 from n where rn = 1 order by c2
```

Comment: doesn't work, plus, in the final tabel, i need to have only de C1,C2 and C3 coll

Comment: Why don't you explain why it doesn't work @jorsep are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

use this following query for your purpose,

```
SELECT max(c1),max(c2),max(c3) FROM `table1` GROUP by c1,c2 order by c4 desc,c1 asc,c2 asc
```

Comment: table.C4 is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.